# Display all variants

Tags: python, vcf-vcard, zarr

I have a 2GB vcf DNA file and I am trying to use vcf_to_zarr() to print out all the variant with all fixed fields but I am getting the error KeyError: 'variants/*'

[allel.vcf_to_zarr](https://scikit-allel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html#allel.vcf_to_zarr)

```html
import allel
import numcodecs
import zarr

def readVcf():

    allel.vcf_to_zarr('actual.vcf', 'example.zarr', fields='*', overwrite=True)
    callset = zarr.open_group('example.zarr', mode='r')
    allfield=callset['variants/*']

    for a in allfield:
         print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over all variants fields, do:

```
for a in callset['variants']:
    print(a)
```

Zarr does not understand wild cards ('*') in hierarchy paths.